# Rspec stub block call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I want to test this block of code. I tried different ways but not able to call .update method of service object. any help will be appreciated basically I want to Test  update_data method

```
process() do
  service(user.id).update(batch) do |p|
    update_data(p)
  end
end
```

Comment: I am able to call process() method and service method returns the service object. which has  update method.

Comment: add to description your spec file with expectations please